# udev high cpu problem

Tags: udev, cpu, modem

i just reinstalled KUbuntu 16.04.4 64bits on my toshiba.

Here https://pastebin.com/qKVpp0re is the result of the udevadm monitor command.
   KERNEL[8960.854968] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)

```
KERNEL[8960.873727] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
UDEV  [8960.874379] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8960.920367] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8960.940873] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8960.959130] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
UDEV  [8960.959673] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8961.019016] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8961.040399] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
UDEV  [8961.056608] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
KERNEL[8961.059447] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
```

Here is another paste https://pastebin.com/gJjFveZq for the udevadm monitor --environment --udev

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [10395.992899] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1 (block)
.MM_USBIFNUM=05
ACTION=change
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3:1.5-scsi-0:0:0:0 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-MARVELL_Mobile_CMCC_CD_200806006809080000-0:0
DEVNAME=/dev/sr1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.5/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sr1
DEVTYPE=disk
DISK_MEDIA_CHANGE=1
ID_BUS=usb
ID_CDROM=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_CD=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT_DATA=1
ID_CDROM_MRW=1
ID_CDROM_MRW_W=1
ID_FOR_SEAT=block-pci-0000_00_1d_7-usb-0_3_1_5-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=Mobile_CMCC_CD
ID_MODEL_ENC=Mobile\x20CMCC\x20CD\x20\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=4e31
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3:1.5-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1d_7-usb-0_3_1_5-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=1.25
ID_SERIAL=MARVELL_Mobile_CMCC_CD_200806006809080000-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=200806006809080000
ID_TYPE=cd
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:e00103:0a0000:ff0000:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=05
ID_VENDOR=MARVELL
ID_VENDOR_ENC=MARVELL\x20
ID_VENDOR_ID=1286
MAJOR=11
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=349650
SUBSYSTEM=block
TAGS=:seat:systemd:uaccess:
```

I have a marvell 4G LTE MIFI that has a micro SD card reader.

I am not an udev specialist but i can see that is the cause.

Comment: The Marvell 4G LTE MIFI dongle seems to have a feature that it initially presents itself as a CD-ROM drive, probably in order to provide a virtual driver CD for a Windows or perhaps Mac system. Once the appropriate driver is installed, it switches the device to another mode to allow its actual features to be used. Linux handles this a bit differently. First, you'll need `usb_modeswitch` installed: check for that in your distribution's package manager. If it's already installed or installing it does not help, then you'll also need a specific usb_modeswitch configuration for that device model.